# python-pcl Segmentation_PointXYZI' object has no attribute 'set_MaxIterations'

Tags: python, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, lidar

I'm new in C++. So, I'm trying to use python-pcl, but I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'pcl._pcl.Segmentation_PointXYZI' object has no attribute 'set_MaxIterations'
```

I'm trying to create the segmentation object for the planar model and set the parameters with the PointXYZI type. I have to use PointXYZI. How can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
def cluster_extraction(self,data):

    print("Type1: ", type(data))

    cloud_filtered = self.downsampling(data,0.3)     

    print("Type2: ", type(cloud_filtered))  

    seg = cloud_filtered.make_segmenter()
    seg.set_optimize_coefficients (True)
    seg.set_model_type (pcl.SACMODEL_PLANE)
    seg.set_method_type (pcl.SAC_RANSAC)
    seg.set_MaxIterations (100)
    seg.set_distance_threshold (0.02)
```

Output:

```
('Type1: ', <type 'pcl._pcl.PointCloud_PointXYZI'>)
('Type2: ', <type 'pcl._pcl.PointCloud_PointXYZI'>)
[ERROR] [1596926303.890116]: bad callback: <bound method sub_pub_node.callback of <__main__.sub_pub_node object at 0x7f154be44ad0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "node.py", line 154, in callback
    downsampled_data = self.processing(pcl2_data)
  File "node.py", line 103, in processing
    processing.cluster_extraction(pcl2_data)
  File "node.py", line 43, in cluster_extraction
    seg.set_MaxIterations (100)
AttributeError: 'pcl._pcl.Segmentation_PointXYZI' object has no attribute 'set_MaxIterations'
```

Comment: please provide the (minimal) code example that raises this error

Comment: I added my code and output.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from where you got your *python-pcl* package, but I will assume that you used [this](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl) one, therefore, and because there is no method called `set_MaxIterations(int )` in the `Segmentation_PointXYZI` class (Sample Consensus), you can try to replace it with `setMaxIterations(int )`.

Inside the definition of the `PointCloud_PointXYZI` class, you can find that the Segmentation method used for this type of point clouds is an instance from `pcl_seg.SACSegmentation_PointXYZI_t` which defines the method for setting the max number of iterations as `setMaxIterations(int )`.

Please check the documentation provided [here](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl) and check the functions that you are using and how are they defined. (I know that can be tedious but it is necessary).

I hope this helped in solving the issue.

Comment: setMaxIterations(int ) did not work. Also, set_MaxIterations(int ) is not defined for Segmentation_PointXYZI class. Paths for related function: "pcl/pxi/Segmentation/Segmentation_(172-180).pxi" . If I add this function into Segmentation_PointXYZI class directly, Does it work?

Comment: Did you check if you can just omit that call? Try to run your script without that.

Answer (score 0):

According to strawlab's [official example](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl/blob/master/examples/official/Segmentation/Plane_model_segmentation.py) the correct call is:

`seg.set_max_iterations(100)`

Comment: It doesn't work. The cloud type is  pcl.PointCloud() in this example. I know that function seg.set_MaxIterations (100) works with pcl.PointCloud().